# finall() in Spring services

Tags: spring, filter, repository, spring-data-jpa, findall

Yesterday I've got access to the new project in my company and I have found this

```
public List<User> findNotActiveUsers() {
    return this.userRepository.findAll().splititerator()
            .filter(u -> u.isActive())
            .collect(Collect.toList());
}
```

Is this a good way to find all the active users? Or should it be done in a repository like this?

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, User> {
    @Query("SELECT user FROM User user WHERE user.active IS TRUE")
    List<User> findActiveUsers();
}
```

And If first solution is correct what about performance?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, both options fulfill the requirement.

However, the **option 2** makes more sense to filter the data at query level rather than at Java level. I believe the performance would be better on the second option though I don't have any data to backup this statement. I have commented about the performance based on my experience.

You can also consider whether Cache (@Cacheable) can be used. It purely depends on the use case i.e. how frequently the User entity is changed and how frequently you would like to refresh the cache.

One disadvantage of using native query is that currently Spring JPA doesn't support execution of dynamic sorting for native queries.

Please refer the similar question discussed in the below link though it is very much related to Hibernate. Clearly, the option 3 is preferred (i.e. @Query approach).

[Spring Data Repository with ORM, EntityManager, @Query, what is the most elegant way to deal with custom SQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986666/spring-data-repository-with-orm-entitymanager-query-what-is-the-most-elegant)